# Split a list of strings between two points

Tags: r, regex, stringr

`c("1x Tomatoes 1kg R 16", "1x Oyster Mushroom R 20", "1x Potatoes 1 kg R 15")`

I have a long list like this and I need to split the strings between the `x` and the `R` in each string so i can have an equal amount of columns when i make a data frame and i cant just split by spaces because not every item on this list are two word products some of them are 2-4 word long so splitting by spaces isn't gonna work.

EDIT:

This is the actual file ive tried to filter a bit down getting rid of useless words so i can make a data frame

```
1x Tomatoes 1kg for R 16 each
1x Oyster Mushroom for R 20 each
1x Potatoes 1 kg for R 15 each
1x Stirfry 400g for R 20 each
2x Red apples 4 medium for R 10 each
1x beef Fillet Steak 300g for R 54 each
1x Beef Rump Steak 300g for R 45 each
1x Back Bacon 200g for R 30 each
1x Gouda 1kg for R 130 each
1x Chicken flattie lemon and herb for R 85 each
2x Lean Beef Mince for R 54 each
```

[image]

i know the pattern list is useless and this is a big mess but thanks for helping.

I'm thinking now that splitting between the `x` and the `R` isn't the best because of other products having capital `R`'s in them

Comment: Can you provide your expected output?

Comment: [1]"1x", "Tomatoes 1kg", "R 16"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
chr <- c("1x Tomatoes 1kg R 16", "1x Oyster Mushroom R 20", "1x Potatoes 1 kg R 15")
strsplit(chr, "(?<=x) | (?=R)", perl = TRUE)
```

If you need to convert the results into a dataframe, then

```
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(chr, "(?<=x) | (?=R)", perl = TRUE)))
```

Should be case sensitive if you are using R v 4.0.2

[image]

**Update**

How about this?

```
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(sub(" each$", "", vec), "(?<=\\dx) | for ", perl = TRUE)))
```

Input

```
> vec
 [1] "1x Tomatoes 1kg for R 16 each"                   "1x Oyster Mushroom for R 20 each"                "1x Potatoes 1 kg for R 15 each"                 
 [4] "1x Stirfry 400g for R 20 each"                   "2x Red apples 4 medium for R 10 each"            "1x beef Fillet Steak 300g for R 54 each"        
 [7] "1x Beef Rump Steak 300g for R 45 each"           "1x Back Bacon 200g for R 30 each"                "1x Gouda 1kg for R 130 each"                    
[10] "1x Chicken flattie lemon and herb for R 85 each" "2x Lean Beef Mince for R 54 each"
```

Output

```
   V1                             V2    V3
1  1x                   Tomatoes 1kg  R 16
2  1x                Oyster Mushroom  R 20
3  1x                  Potatoes 1 kg  R 15
4  1x                   Stirfry 400g  R 20
5  2x            Red apples 4 medium  R 10
6  1x         beef Fillet Steak 300g  R 54
7  1x           Beef Rump Steak 300g  R 45
8  1x                Back Bacon 200g  R 30
9  1x                      Gouda 1kg R 130
10 1x Chicken flattie lemon and herb  R 85
11 2x                Lean Beef Mince  R 54
```

Comment: i did that but now its splitting items like `"Beef rump steak"` on the `r` in the string is there a way to only make it a capital R because the only capital R in the list of products is the Rand symbol

Comment: @Noodle18 Hi, I can't reproduce this problem. Are you using the latest version of R?

Comment: i am using R 4.02 but ill make an edit quick and show you my whole process in an edit quick which is gonna look really dumb but im still learning so bear with me.

Comment: its perfect thank you and I definitely learnt quite a bit today so thanks to everybody too.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: If you always have "for R ..." then change the approach below as
`matches <- stringr::str_match(string, "x\\s*(.*?)\\s*for R")[,2]`

You can try `str_match` from the {stringr} package like this:

```r
string <- c("1x Tomatoes 1kg R 16", "1x Oyster Mushroom R 20", "1x Potatoes 1 kg R 15")
matches <- stringr::str_match(string, "x\\s*(.*?)\\s*R")[,2]
matches
#> [1] "Tomatoes 1kg"    "Oyster Mushroom" "Potatoes 1 kg"
```

Created on 2020-10-19 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)

Answer (score 0):

This should work (all with base R):

```
x <- c("1x Tomatoes 1kg R 16", "1x Oyster Mushroom R 20", "1x Potatoes 1 kg R 15")

x <- t(matrix(unlist(x = strsplit(x = unlist(strsplit(x,
                                             split = ' R ')),
                                split = 'x ')),
            ncol = 3))

x <- as.data.frame(x)
```